# writing a program to normalise values across uneven tables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization

So lets take two uneven tables

```
year <- c(1999,1999,1998,1997,2000,1999,1998)
distance <- c(45,50,60,40,35,45,40)
df1 <- data.frame(year, distance)
```

and the summary data

```
unique_year <- c(1997,1998,1999,2000)
distance_total <- c(40,100,140,35)
df2 <- data.frame(unique_year, distance_total)
```

Now I want to create a new variable `df1$normailsed_distance` which takes the `distance` values and then divides it by the corresponding `distance_total` for each unique year.

So `df1$normailsed_distance[1]` == 0.321.
Which comes from (45/140)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `merge` to join the two datasets by 'year/unique_year' in 'df1/df2' and transform the output dataset by creating a new column 'normalised_distance' which is the ratio of 'distance/distance_total`

```
  transform(merge(df1, df2, by.x='year', by.y='unique_year'),
               normalised_distance=distance/distance_total)[,-3]
```

Or use `match`

```
 df1$normalised_distance <- df1$distance/df2$distance_total[match(df1$year
                 , df2$unique_year)]
```

---

If you don't want to compare the columns in both the dataset, but use from the same dataset, this could be done with standard aggregate by group options.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, normalised_distance := distance/sum(distance), year]
```

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$normalised_distance <- with(df1, ave(distance, year,
                        FUN=function(x) x/sum(x)))
```

Or similar method can be done with `dplyr`.  @Khashaa already showed that in the comments (and deleted).

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(normalised_distance = distance/sum(distance))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply merge those data frames and then compute distances:

```
df <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by.x = "year", by.y = "unique_year")
df$normalised <- df$distance / df$distance_total
```

which would produce:

```
> head(df)
  year distance distance_total normalised
1 1997       40             40  1.0000000
2 1998       60            100  0.6000000
3 1998       40            100  0.4000000
4 1999       45            140  0.3214286
5 1999       50            140  0.3571429
6 1999       45            140  0.3214286
```

Comment: @akrun true, I was typing when you posted. I'm happy to delete, if you wish.